# Python MySQL Injection Failed

Tags: python, mysql, sql-injection

I'm trying to demonstrate a SQL injection in my app using Python Flask and MySQL. Various references have mentioned that only 1 query can be run at a time, but even when I tried to do it to run 1 query only, I haven't been able to succeed yet. My code is below. I know that the login_email parameter has made it to the query since I'm able to print it. If the query ran successfully, the result should be printed out at the bottom.

```
print(request.form['login_email'])
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %(email)s;"
data = { "email" : request.form["login_email"] }
result = mysql.query_db(query, data)
print(result)
```

What I tried to input:
' or '1'='1

Comment: you can try print out the content of ```query``` to see if it is quoted,  most modern web framework is aware of SQL Injection , and somehow  not that easy to break in

Comment: @bigdataolddriver: When I add in print(query), it prints out: SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = %(email)s;   But in my terminal, it shows the following: Running Query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '\' or \'1\'=\'1';

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about. You're using the mechanism to escape inputs in order to avoid injection and asking why it doesn't allow injection? The purpose doesn't make sense.

Comment: the point @roganjosh talking about,  ```mysql.query_db``` is a  injection defensive way of querying  , if you keeping on using it ,  basically no injection can happen

Comment: I didn't know about that before.

Answer (score -1):

I think your SQL query is like this as below:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}';"
```

Comment: I did that and now my terminal displays: Something went wrong (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM users WHERE email = '\\' or \\'1\\'=\\'1'' at line 1")

Comment: Try this one query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}';"

Comment: If not remove square brackets then try

Comment: Neither works. I'm getting back "()" when I print(result).

Comment: You are getting empty result I think there is no matching result. What was the earlier result

Comment: Answering a Python question with a PHP string? The blind leading the blind here.